# How can I use Gulp to run a Node JS app?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a node app "generate.js" that generates a set of static files.

My goal is that when ever any files in /foo/ directory are modified, that generate.js is run once.

And, I would like to do this using a Gulp watch task.

In the past, I have done similar using Grunt and the grunt-execute plugin. But, I haven't found a way to do it with Gulp.

Comment: Might be worth checking out foundation for apps' gulpfile for some examples. https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1):

Gulp code is ordinary javascript. So you can just run your process using node's built in `child_process` module.

```
var cp = import('child_process');

gulp.task('taskname', function(callback) {
    // Start your child process here
    cp.spawn(/*...*/);
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I wasn't able to get it working exactly as your example. Instead I did this: http://jsbin.com/hebiweqira/edit?js